# Casting to Percentage in SQL Accuracy Issues

Tags: sql, reporting-services, percentage

I'm working on a report which requires me to aggregate survey data and display it as a percentage.

My SQL looks like this:

```
CAST(ROUND(100.0 * SUM(Agree)/SUM(Total), 2) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS 'Agree',
CAST(ROUND(100.0 * SUM(StronglyAgree)/SUM(Total), 2) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS 'Strongly Agree'
```

etc

In one surveyI have a total of 57 responses, 35 Agree, 21 strongly agree, using the above query it translates to 61.4% agree and 36.84 strongly agree giving me a total of 98.24.

I'm not sure this level of accuracy is acceptable.  Is there any way I can make it more accurate?

Comment: "57 responses, 35 Agree, 21 strongly agree" **35 + 21 = 56** then 1/57 is approx (1.7) your missing percentage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks everything is ok:

> 57 responses, 35 Agree, 21 strongly agree

21 + 35 = 56

So there is missing 1 vote.

```
1/57 is approx 1.7 percent point
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right I was missing a vote! Bad data... Thanks for the fresh set of eyes on this :)